# Multiple Eddystone-URL/UID's from same Bluetooth Beacon?

Tags: bluetooth, beacon

Is it possible to program a BT beacon to advertise a sequence of different Eddystone-URL/UID's in sequence?  I imagine I could from something like a Raspberry Pi3 with a BT adapter, but I was wondering about something like an actual beacon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.   This technique is called "interleaving", and it is possible to do with both software beacons and hardware beacons.

Eddystone actually relies on this technique in order to match its multiple frames.  When a receiver sees an Eddystone-TLM frame coming from the same device as Eddystone-URL  or Eddystone-UID, it knows that the telemetry is for that beacon frame.

Using the same technique, it is possible to send out multiple URL or UID frames from the same device using different identifiers for each frame.  Some commercial manufacturers such as Radius Networks support doing this in some of their products.

Comment: I saw the TLM stuff, but that doesn't interest me, only URL/UID.  Say I was in a department store in the ladies section and I wanted a beacon advertising a handbag URL every second while every 2 seconds it'd advertise a URL for perfume.  Something like that.

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible.  I do not know of commercial off the shelf beacons that do exactly what you say in the above comment, but you could certainly build your own.  I have built lots of projects with custom BLE transmitters that send different  beacon values at different times.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So it's a question of setting up the internal infrastructure.  You'll have to forgive me, I'm new to this game and I've not see much out there.  I'm looking at the NordicSemiconductor NRF line at the moment.  If you have any resources on how, I'd love to look at them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. Im pretty sure you would need to have some smart device nearby that is running a program that is periodically changing the UIDs. The micro-controllers that power these beacons are pretty bare bones and are really optimized for transmitting bluetooth signals.

Comment: I posted a comment to @davidgyoung above that had more of what I had in mind.  Sounds like you're saying no, at least as far as programming the beacon directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it.

EddyStone supports four types of payloads/frame-formats i.e, UID, URL, TLM, and EID.

Eddystone UID/EID are the frame-formats to use for this purpose.

As far as using the 'NordicSemiconductor NRF line' of beacons just make sure that these are fully Eddystone compliant i.e, support the EID frame-format.

Freely available Google Beacon Cloud platform is great for trying this out (called 'registering and provisioning your beacon').

It can be implemented w/o building or requiring any custom app at the client end.

On the client-side. 
Use 'Google Nearby Notifications' & 'Google Nearby Messages'

On the server/cloud-side. 
Google Proximity API for 'registering and provisioning your beacon'
Use 'Google Nearby Messages' API

Good luck with your project .